# Accessing object property in Typescript using variable

Tags: typescript, object, properties, typeof, keyof

I have following model

```
interface Budget {
    budget_july?: number,
    budget_august?: number,
    budget_september?: number,
    budget_october?: number,
    budget_november?: number,
    budget_december?: number,
    budget_january?: number,
    budget_february?: number,
    budget_march?: number,
    budget_april?: number,
    budget_may?: number,
    budget_june?: number
}
```

I am trying to trying to access the property dynamically using a variable, like so:

```
const budgets: Budget[] = [];

var datestr = '2022-07-01';

const budget_month: keyof Budget = 'budget_' + new Date(datestr).toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }).toLowerCase();
budgets[0][budget_month] = 5000;
```

Here I get error : *Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof Budget'*

Following works:

```
const budget_month = 'budget_july';  budgets[0][budget_month] = 5000;
```

I have worked out a workaround using switch/case but its ugly. Is it possible to make this work like I did here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript can't track all that string transformation and know that it will be a `keyof Budget` at the end.

I think you may be better off with a type assertion that casts the `string` to a `keyof Budget`:

```
const budget_month =
  'budget_' +
  new Date(datestr)
    .toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })
    .toLowerCase() as keyof Budget;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. But I'm still getting error when I try to assign a value to the property like here: 
let _budget: Budget = {}; 
_budget[budget_month] = 5000; //Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: I got it working by setting const budgets: any[] = []; but still would prefer if someone could explain why I couldn't use array of type Budget.

Comment: This works fine for me. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFcAmBzCZkDeAUMqcgEZa5gD6AVugDYCeA-AFzIjoC250AGhJlKOPDTjps6AM5gOXXvyhCyFKuJkQADpD7QF3fSuGlR1GgHsEYS8sNLBp9WNohLANwjGHx1SI1aTAgkH04jZX8zQPo4bjgoNnDHEzVzcRgIcih0BKTFP2d02h4EhAALX0iimLhtKGBGKqc0mNL8iJaA13p0EAhmqCIAXyIiBEsQORdqGU4MVwBtAF1kAF5kFYBuMY8E5Ew4SDkodeQAcgAmAAZLy4Baa4B2R4BGc53xyenimh5JsDlM7nX7nZAAai4EAA7sgACJHCAACkOxzAUAAlAA6WwAGWscEYEAAyujQNgkedgvAmGBzgJCMh-uBypxzoxJtgwcNsXjLNDoABhOBaJEY5Ai5AAawgzEsMDQgR2xRki2uy0Wv2ZgNWGwArNdDVsgA) How is your code different?

Comment: My [implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-2uw4xm?file=/index.ts) is a tiny bit different as I also have some mandatory properties.